# add react component to existing webpage and avoid CSS conflicts

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a React/MaterialUI component that will be embedded in existing websites.

In order to minimise the work needed on the existing page to embed my component, I'm bundling my component into an app.js and the only change requested to the existing page is something like:

```
<div id="embedded-component"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/app.js"></script>
```

my component finds the div by ID and then mounts on that element.

Things are mostly working but I'm having issues with CSS conflicts between the CSS files on the original page (which I can't modify) and the elements of my application.

For example the original page uses text input elements with a border/padding/color that I don't want my component to "inherit". 
**I want my component to display the same way regardless of which page is embedded on.**

**Is there any strategy/tool to use in this case, so CSS classes on existing page do not affect the elements of my embedded component?**

Trying to find a solution to this I've come across the Shadow DOM (e.g. https://medium.com/rate-engineering/winning-the-war-of-css-conflicts-through-the-shadow-dom-de6c797b5cba) but I'm not sure how widely supported this is in different browsers.

Is there any solution to this, that is widely supported by all major browsers?

I cannot use iframes and have full control of my js/css files but no control over the existing page other than the "mounting" div.

Comment: Are you tried overwriting the properties that you have conflicts?

Comment: You might want to look into reset stylesheets: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  You will have to reset with the same specificity that they were originally declared.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying not to have to overwrite CSS conflicts explicitly as my component will be embedded in many different webpages which would need a different/specific overwriting logic for each page.

I am using MaterialUI's CSSBaseline which, if I understand correctly, should have some CSS resets.

Comment: @user2987504 have you found a solution for your problem? I have a similar issue.

Comment: in the end I had to use iframes although I was trying not to. Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@ryanseddon/rendering-to-iframes-in-react-d1cb92274f86